# ffmpeg output images filename with time position

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, screenshot, filenames, frame

I am using ffmpeg to get some jpg from my video at a specific rate (one screenshot every 5 seconds) with this command :

```
ffmpeg -i source -f image2 -r 1/5 %d.jpg
```

This works and give me sequential filenames :

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
```

What if I need to know at which time those screenshots have been taken ? Something like a timestamp :

```
00:00:00.0000.jpg
00:00:05.0000.jpg
00:00:10.0000.jpg
00:00:15.0000.jpg
```

or the number of seconds :

```
0.jpg
5.jpg
10.jpg
15.jpg
```

I tried again with the new [-frame_pts](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-6) option :

```
ffmpeg -i source -f image2 -r 1/5 -frame_pts 1 %d.jpg
```

I got similar sequential filenames, but now they are starting from zero :

```
0.jpg
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i source -vf fps=1,select='not(mod(t,5))' -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 z%d.jpg
```

frame_pts will assign a serial number to the image name, where the number represents the frame position as per the output timebase. So the calculated time position is `frame #` x `timebase`. The timebase is the reciprocal of the output framerate e.g. for a 12 fps stream, timebase is 1/12. So output file `image212` represents a time of `212` x `1/12` = `17.67s`

To represent seconds, you need to generate a 1 fps stream and then pick every 5th frame, to get a frame from every 5th second. The `vsync 0`  is added to prevent ffmpeg from duplicating frames to generate a constant frame rate stream.

Comment: What if the frame rate is variable? The computation here assumes that the frame rate is constant and simply divides the frame index by the frame rate. Is there a way to get the actual time-stamp of each frame, under the assumption that the frame rate is not supposedly constant?

Comment: Is it possible to just assign the timestamp as the filename?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but it does the job

```
for (i = 0; i < $duration; $i += 0.5) { //where $duration is video duration 
   `ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -ss $i -vframes 1 $i.jpg`
}
```

Of course this would be very slow since it spawns ffmpeg for every frame but as I said may help you to get the job done.