# FFmpeg extract every frame with timestamp

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

How can I extract every frame of an video with the respective timestamp?

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i in.mp4 images/frame-%d.jpg
```

This code extracts all frames, but without timestamp. Since Windows do not allow ":" in filenames, I'll replace it for ".". I would like something like this:

```
frame-h.m.s.ms.random_value.jpg
frame-00.10.15.17.1.jpg
frame-00.11.16.04.2.jpg
frame-00.11.17.11.3.jpg
frame-00.11.17.22.4.jpg
frame-00.12.04.01.5.jpg
...
```

The reason of "random id" is to allow repeated frames without replacing them.

I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i rabbit.mp4 images/frame-%{pts\:hms}.jpg
```

But this doesn't work! => Could not open file : images/

I have no clue how can I do that! Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099869/ffmpeg-output-images-filename-with-time-position

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1,select='not(mod(t,5))' -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 z%d.jpg` = `Missing ')' or too many args in 'mod(t'`

Comment: `ffmpeg -r 1 -i rabbit.mp4 -frame_pts 1 -vsync 0 test/%03d.jpg` generate files in sequential numbers, without timestamp in filename

Comment: Try this, it'll use the input timebase:  `ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0:v:0 -vsync 0 -copyts -enc_time_base -1 -frame_pts 1 test/%03d.jpg`

Comment: Hello, the output => https://prnt.sc/1u4c6g4 || Still appear like sequential numbers but with different format yet

Comment: Remove `-vf` filters and add `-r 1000` to my command.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 1000 -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 test2/z%d.jpg` => https://prnt.sc/1u6roob || This is not what I'm asking for

Comment: I was able to create this command to do my job, but it's taking a long time to complete and generating useless images/frames. Do you know if there's a way to speed up this process? => `for i in {00..00}:{00..36}:{00..46}.{00..99}
do
    ffmpeg -ss $i -i input.mp4 -vframes 1 -q:v 2 frames/$i.jpg
done`

Comment: @RuanMatt the "sequential numbers" you get when you use `-frame_pts` are the presentation timestamps of the frames, either using the input timebase or milliseconds for  `-r 1000`.  They're just not in H:M:S format.

Comment: I cannot use `-r 1000`. How do I convert from timebase to milliseconds?